# AWS API-Gateway doesn't fully allow CORS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

CORS is still a little mysterious to me but when trying to add CORS support to an API endpoint on AWS API-Gateway I get the following report:

[image]

I'm unsure why the GET method can't be configured correctly and when I try to call this endpoint (a cross domain call) I get the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Odd that the two operations on the GET method aren't working. Do you have the GET method set up already? Maybe a permissions issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this yourself. Create a GET method (if it is not present already) and add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with a value of '*' (or whatever is correct in your situation) to the response.

Comment: yeah I do have a GET method. If I pass a Headers param from Lambda will that be proxied through to API Gateway?

Comment: If you use the lambda proxy integration then yes, automatically. If not, then you need to setup the mapping yourself.

Comment: This would do the trick, the 'Enable CORS' option in the console just automates some actions you can execute manually yourself, including adding the CORS headers to the GET method response. Note that the single quotes MUST be used in the header value. So, literally '*'.